# Issue with User Profile in User Profile Application

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

I have SharePoint 2013 Ent. I have successfully configure User Profile Service Application. My User Profile Synchronize Server is also started successfully. I did AD connection with Auto discover domain controller and done full synchronization.

My AD is something like this `CROP.XYZCompany.COM`. when we login we do something like this `XYZ\Username`

But whenever I check user profile I am getting CROP\Username why is it so? I need `XYZ\Username`

I try to delete service and reconfigure but always the same bahavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your Forest Name and NetBIOS name are different. You have to follow the guide from Spence Harbar: http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx . It was written for 2010 but still applies to 2013.

After you create the UPA and before you import profiles you have to set `NetBIOSDomainNamesEnabled` to true.

```
$upsa = Get-SPServiceApplication –Id <GUID of User Profile Service Application>
$upsa.NetBIOSDomainNamesEnabled=1
$upsa.Update()
```